# Incollection book titles in italics using custom-bib

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I've been trying to create a custom bibliography style using custom-bib (makebst), and I have almost succeeded. The only thing that I've failed to fix is the incollection and inproceedings book titles; they should be in italics, but, instead, they are between quotation marks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's my tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{authordate1-4}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\cite{prawitz1975}
\cite{sher2008}
\cite{macfarlane2009}

\bibliographystyle{abnt}
\bibliography{mestrado}

\end{document}
```

And here's what I get as a result:

[image: Result from the above code]
And here's the code from the .bst file for the incollection and inproceedings functions:

```
FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      end.quote.btitle
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
  format.edition output
  format.chapter.pages output
  new.sentence
  format.publisher.address output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.isbn output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  format.eprint output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      end.quote.btitle
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher empty$
        { format.organization.address output }
        { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
      format.date "year" output.check
      format.isbn output
      format.issn output
    }
```

Comment: Is `biblatex` an option? It would make your life a *lot* easier...

Comment: I'd rather stick to what I'm currently using. Still, why do you think biblatex is better than what I'm currently using?

Comment: It is much more flexible and powerful than `bibtex` and it can be customised in LaTeX rather than a separate language. It can use `biber` which makes much more powerful sorting possible, adds further flexibility and removes the limitations on the use of large databases. Working with UTF-8 encoded databases is entirely straightforward. The ability to handle multiple bibliographies, split bibliographies and categorised bibliographies is built in. More flexible cross-referencing, cleaner `bib` files, use of non `bib` formats and remote databases, context-sensitive punctuation... no more room!

Comment: Well, it doesn't seem to support .bst files using BibTex as the backend, so I'm not sure if that's an option.

Comment: It doesn't use `bst` files, no. That is intended to be a feature ;). By the way, you shouldn't really cite MacFarlane's article like that. SEP recommends only citing an archived edition or (where really necessary) making clear you are using the in-progress version. See http://plato.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/encyclopedia/archinfo.cgi?entry=logical-constants. (And the name of the encyclopaedia etc. is omitted in your reference.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'd still like to know how to adapt my .bst file, though.